# How can I migrate from CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes to stringByAddingPercentEncodingWIthAllowedCharacters?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, deprecated

In my code, the method CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes is marked as deprecated as of iOS 9. My code is as follows:

```
static NSString *encodeByAddingPercentEscapes(NSString *input) {
    NSString *encodedValue = (NSString *)CFBridgingRelease(CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes(kCFAllocatorDefault, (CFStringRef)input, NULL, (CFStringRef)@"!*'();:@&=+$,/?%#[]", kCFStringEncodingUTF8));
    return encodedValue;
}
```

The warning suggests that I use `[NSString stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters:]`

How can I accomplish the same result using the newer method?

Answer (score 0):

you can use [@"" stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters:[NSCharacterSet URLQueryAllowedCharacterSet]].
And there are many set to use:URLPathAllowedCharacterSet、URLQueryAllowedCharacterSet.etc